# Why does creating a private property in my class throw syntaxError: unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, class, tree

I am trying to implement a filesystem tree. I am creating a directory class which looks like this

```
const DIRECTORY_TYPE = {
    DEFAULT: 'DEFAULT'
}

class Directory{
    #name
    #type: DIRECTORY_TYPE.DEFAULT;
    #children = new Map()
    #parent = null
```

When I try to instantiate it as

```
const dir = new Directory('root')

console.log(dir.name)
```

the `#type: DIRECTORY_TYPE.DEFAULT` throws the error

I have tried reassigning `const` to `let` but I have no other solutions. I expected that it would just allow me to create the class and return `root`

Comment: Your class syntax is wrong.

Comment: `#type:` should be `#type =`

Comment: The `:` symbol is wrong. Are you trying to use typescript or not?

Comment: Thank you. I was following along in a tutorial and that's how they defined it in their code.

Answer (score 1):

1. your syntax is wrong, it should be

```
 #type = DIRECTORY_TYPE.DEFAULT;
```

2. You can't access a private property outside of a class, read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: Thank you. I was following along in a tutorial and that's how they defined it in JS. I wonder why theirs was able to work

Comment: I wonder too. :) Feel free to read more about it in the link I shared, and please mark the answer as correct if it is